# Symfony simple form filter question only allow unique entries

Tags: symfony

I'm stuck for a while now in trying to get the following scenario to work.
I have a registration system for a sporting team.
Each team can register for any available contest. The problem is that each team is only allowed once to register on a contest. I simply want to filter the teams that are already registered for the current selected contest. I'm using the Symfony framework together with Doctrine ORM and the symfony form system.

I tried to create a custom function inside the teamRepository to only get the teams that are not registered for a given contest. But i can't seem to find a way to gt this to work.
I'm using 3 entities for this: User, Team, Registration, Contest
The registration entity holds all te submitted registrations with a relation to the Contest and the User (team). I hope that someone can help me here. For reference, this is my registration entity:

class Registrations
{
use TimestampableEntity;

```
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Team::class, inversedBy: 'registrations')]
private $Team;

#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Dancers::class, inversedBy: 'registrations', fetch: 'EAGER')]
private $Dancers;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'text', nullable: true)]
private $Comments;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: Contest::class, fetch: 'EAGER', inversedBy: 'registrations')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private $Contest;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
#[Gedmo\Blameable(on: 'create')]
private $RegisteredBy;

#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'Registration', targetEntity: Orders::class)]
private $orders;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
private $MusicFile;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->Dancers = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTeam(): ?Team
{
    return $this->Team;
}

public function setTeam(?Team $Team): self
{
    $this->Team = $Team;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Dancers[]
 */
public function getDancers(): Collection
{
    return $this->Dancers;
}

public function addDancer(Dancers $dancer): self
{
    if (!$this->Dancers->contains($dancer)) {
        $this->Dancers[] = $dancer;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeDancer(Dancers $dancer): self
{
    $this->Dancers->removeElement($dancer);

    return $this;
}

public function getComments(): ?string
{
    return $this->Comments;
}

public function setComments(?string $Comments): self
{
    $this->Comments = $Comments;

    return $this;
}

public function getRegisteredBy(): ?string
{
    return $this->RegisteredBy;
}

public function setRegisteredBy(?string $RegisteredBy): self
{
    $this->RegisteredBy = $RegisteredBy;

    return $this;
}


public function getContest(): ?Contest
{
    return $this->Contest;
}

public function setContest(?Contest $Contest): self
{
    $this->Contest = $Contest;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection<int, Orders>
 */
public function getOrders(): Collection
{
    return $this->orders;
}

public function addOrder(Orders $order): self
{
    if (!$this->orders->contains($order)) {
        $this->orders[] = $order;
        $order->setRegistration($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeOrder(Orders $order): self
{
    if ($this->orders->removeElement($order)) {
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($order->getRegistration() === $this) {
            $order->setRegistration(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getMusicFile(): ?string
{
    return $this->MusicFile;
}

public function setMusicFile(string $MusicFile): self
{
    $this->MusicFile = $MusicFile;

    return $this;
}
```

}

This is the repo function as mentioned:

```
    public function getTeamsNotRegistered($organisation, $contest)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->leftJoin('t.Registrations', 'r')
        ->andWhere('t.Organisation = :org')
        ->andWhere('r.Contest = :contest')
        ->setParameter('org', $organisation)
        ->setParameter('contest', $contest)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the mentioned repository with custom function where you use your query builder to get filtered results please?

Comment: Hi @dnaumann i added the function to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I can see there is also `organisation` but you don't describe it. Why do you use this in where condition in `getTeamsNotRegistered()` ? If team is in organisation and you want to see all registered teams, this should not be there, right?

Comment: @KamilP. thanks for youre answer. Indeed i forgot to mention that there is also an orginastion entity wich the user is linked to. The reason it is included in the query is that i only want to show the teams that are related to the organisation the current user is part of.